# How to 301 redirect to another url with .htaccess on Heroku

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, heroku, google-search-console

recently i have changed my heroku's app name and url. From  http://cerobull.herokuapp.com to http://cerobullyingapp.herokuapp.com.
The problem is that i had the url  http://cerobull.herokuapp.com indexed in google via google search console and now that i changed the url nothing works.
Im trying to do an adress change in the google search console but it says that i have to do some 301 redirects in the .htacces file but in heroku it doesnt work like that.
How can i do a 301 redirect on heroku (my app is a flask app)?
Thanks

Comment: Not sure if you can do that at all, if you just changed your project name on heroku - I’d guess you would need access to _both_, so that you can configure what should happen when the “old” URL gets requested. If you just _renamed_ your project, then heroku probably has no idea that it should route the old URL to your project at all now.

Comment: Have a look at this: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains I know it works if you own a custom domain. Not sure if it still works if you are pointing to another (sub)domain you do not technically own. You can also deploy a Heroku app with URL redirection but I don't know if it is Google SEO compatible.

Comment: The problem is that google search console still remembers the old url and when i try to index the new url it doesnt let me because it says that the index page is duplicated (and that the index of the old url is the canonical)